# What can I do about a dead Delta 62-043 table saw motor?

Tags: repair, table-saw

I bought a used Delta 62-043 table saw for $200 about a year ago. It sat in my shed for a while, and I just now turned it on to start a project.

There was some black smoke. I'm embarrassed; I thought it was the wood smoking, because it was a tough cut. But apparently it was the motor, because it just suddenly stopped dead, and won't turn back on.

Any ideas? The only replacement motor I can find is $600+ -- more than the original table saw. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 5):

- You could see if it can be repaired by a local motor shop. They are not inexpensive though.
- You can look on Craigslist for any electric motor with the same specs as yours, the most important being HP, RPM, voltage and frame type. Northern Equipment does offer a replacement that matches your motor specs for $300.
- Verify that the smoke was not just the drive belt. With the belt removed see if the blade spins freely. If something is binding and you can remedy it you may have burned the belt, damaged the motor but not killed it.
- Check the sides and end of the motor for a thermal safety switch: a button, usually red or black, that resets when pushed in.